# Conditional IO action

Tags: haskell, io

I am writing a program that should be able to read input either from the command line directly or from a file depending on what args are passed.  For example.  However I am having trouble making the IO event conditional.  My first thought was to do:

```
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
 cla <- getArgs
 let flags = parseFlags (filter isFlag cla) []
 let args  = filter (not.isFlag) cla
 input <- if (elem "e" flags) then (head args) else (readFile (head args))
```

However this doesn't work because `(head args)` is not a IO action.  My next thought was to do:

```
import System.Environment

main :: IO ()
main = do
 cla <- getArgs
 let flags = parseFlags (filter isFlag cla) []
 let args  = filter (not.isFlag) cla
 file <- (readFile (head args))
 let input = if (elem "e" flags) then (head args) else (file)
```

But this will error if the input is not the name of a file.  Is there a sensible way to do this? Am I approaching the problem incorrectly?

Comment: In your first bit of code, the problem actually looks like `(head args)` isn't an IO action, but `(readFile (head args))` is. Youre returning 2 different types. Try just changing `(head args)` to `(return (head args))` to put the value in the IO monad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for.  If you would like to post an answer detailing this I would be happy to accept.

Comment: Unrelated, but how do you know `args` isn't empty?

Comment: @chepner This code is abbreviated for the sake of clarity.  In the code shown I don't, but in my actual code I have more extensive handling, that ensures that the input provided is valid.  For the same reason the definition of `parseFlags` has been left out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were trying to treat `(head args)` as though it was in the IO monad. Since it's just a raw value, you need to place it into the monad before it can be used as an IO action.

Just change `(head args)` to `(return (head args))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `return (head args)` to lift a type to the `IO` monad.