# Read from file or from command line arguments haskell

Tags: haskell, io, command-line-arguments

I am designing the IO for a program I have written in Haskell.  I would like to be able to read some arguments from file using `-f` or from the command line by default.  The command line arguments get split up into convenient chunks meaning I do not need to parse them.  However this does not happen when reading from file.  So I wrote a simple little parser to do what I wanted.

```
parseFile :: String -> [String]
parseFile [] = [""]
parseFile ('"':xs) = parseString xs '"'
parseFile ('\'':xs) = parseString xs '\''
parseFile (' ':xs) = "":parseFile xs
parseFile ('\t':xs) = "":parseFile xs
parseFile ('\n':xs) = "":parseFile xs
parseFile (s:xs) = (\(a:xa)->(a++[s]):xa)$ parseFile xs

parseString :: String -> Char -> [String]
parseString (s:xs) a
 | s == a = "":parseFile xs
 | otherwise = (\(a:xa)->(a++[s]):xa)$ parseString xs a
```

I thought this would be pretty simple I would do something like

```
let myInput = if (flagDetected) then (parseFile $ readFile $ last args) else (args)
```

However the result of `readFile` is an IO action and not a string thus I cannot parse it.  I've tried a number of configurations all which have fails, mostly for typing reasons.  I've tried assigning the results before parsing, which resulted in a type mismatch between `args` which is a `[[Char]]` ( it is the result of using `getArgs` from the `System.Environment` module) and the result of `readFile` which is still an IO String. 
 I tried wrapping `args` with a `return` which of course doesn't fix this problem because of a type mismatch.  I'm really at a loss of ideas now.  I feel like this is probably a problem with the way I am thinking about the issue.

How can I get the behavior I desire?

[Here's a related question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485607/conditional-io-action).  The root of the problem is the same but the answers on the last one were far to specific to help me here. It seems this is a frequent problem for me.

Comment: write a one linner bash script to parse the input file and invoke your haskell ... post what the parm input file would look like

Comment: What have I done wrong?  Everyone has the right to downvote but it would be helpful if I they could comment so I can get some feedback.

Comment: Downvoters should comment. Anyway, probably you need to read an IO or monad tutorial, like [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output). The idea is that you can use `parseFile <$> readFile (last args)` (or `fmap`, or `do` notation or many other alternatives) and its type will be `IO [String]`. But this is probably one of the most frequent FAQs in Haskell, and is a bit broad, so a tutorial should really be the best option.

Comment: This is a really basic question about how to use `IO`. I recommend thinking about `(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b` (the real type is more general) and how you could use it to make the types fit.

Comment: @chi Thanks for the advice.  I read that a while ago when I first started programming in Haskell.  I probably just forgot the important bits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an inversion of control in the flow of your data.. Haskell's `IO` datatypes are there to manage the effects of i/o operations. Read string from a file is not a fact, the file couldn't exist, can be empty or so on. Many possibilities could happend. So for that reason `main` function use to be based on `IO`. The way you can use to "extract" wrapped value from a IO is using `do-return` block

```
inputIO = if flagDetected then
             do 
               cnt <- (readFile path)
               return (parseFile cnt)
          else return args
main = do
      input <- inputIO
      return yourProgram input
```

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920888/haskell-how-can-i-use-if-statement-in-do-block-properly)

Comment: That was just a pseudo code. Tell me what type args is?

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch

Comment: What type do you want in myInput? [String] or just String?

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch

Comment: `myInput` should be a `[String]`.  Which is why I wrote the parser to turn a `String` into a `[String]`.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch  look at.. I changed the code regarding your comment

Comment: Yes that indeed does work.  I was just writing up an answer doing exactly what your pseudo code does.  thanks